# Message: Undefined variable: beauty_detail in CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter, undefined-variable

I have a form where user can select either **book** or **beauty** radio button. Code is working fine on **book** but showing an error on **beauty**. Code is the same except data fetch from database is different. I have tried but still stuck.

**ERROR**
`A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice 
Message: Undefined variable: beauty_detail 
Filename: controllers/Welcome.php
Line Number: 87`

```
        if($result == 0){
            echo "no recommendation";
        } else{

            foreach($result as $key=>$value){
                $q = $this->mymodel->fetchBeautydetail($key);
                foreach($q as $val){

                    $beauty_detail[$val->user_id]['product_id'] = $val->product_id; 
                    $beauty_detail[$val->user_id]['product_rating'] = $val->rating;
                }
            }
(line number: 87) $this->load->view('beauty_dashboard', ['beauty_detail'=>$beauty_detail]);
        }
```

Comment: Have you set a variable `$beauty_detail = []` anywhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is [scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Try following. (Declaring `beauty_detail` out of foreach)

```
$beauty_detail;
foreach($result as $key=>$value){
                $q = $this->mymodel->fetchBeautydetail($key);
                foreach($q as $val){

                    $beauty_detail[$val->user_id]['product_id'] = $val->product_id; 
                    $beauty_detail[$val->user_id]['product_rating'] = $val->rating;
                }
            }
$this->load->view('beauty_dashboard', ['beauty_detail'=>$beauty_detail]);
        }
```